# Parsing active record object to json with escape of single quote (apostrophe)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to parse a rails active record relation to json.

```
jQuery('.user_form').data('mydata', '<%= raw User.all.to_json %>');
var myPersonalData = JSON.parse(jQuery('.user_form').data('mydata'));
```

Here is my rails object

```
'"[{\"id\":1,\"email\":\"1@2.com\",\"created_at\":\"2016-02-24T12:39:29.184Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2016-02-24T12:39:29.184Z\",\"username\":\"xyz's\",\"skypeid\":null},{\"id\":2,\"email\":\"3@2.com\",\"created_at\":\"2016-02-24T12:39:41.455Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2016-02-24T12:39:41.455Z\",\"username\":\"abs's\",\"skypeid\":null}]"'
```

The problem with this is in the username column the value contains "'" (apostrophe) which breaks the chain of single and double quotes and hence while parsing it from javascript it throws an error.

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list path/to/file:linenumber
```

The problem with this is at '<%= raw User.all.to_json %>'
It get converted to

```
' "object_attribut\": \" value_with'apostrophe" '
```

And hence the portion after ' gets escaped.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can instead use this to_a, `<%= raw User.all.to_a %>`.

Comment: @Sahil, why we need `to_a` here, as per the question, we need send `json` to `javascript` I guess.

Comment: Sorry for that it gives 2D array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `escape_javascript` function provided in `ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper`.

You can read about it [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript), but the basics are that it Escapes carriage returns and single and double quotes for JavaScript segments.

So, what you would end up with is:

```
jQuery('.user_form').data('mydata', '<%= raw escape_javascript(User.all.to_json) %>');
```

Comment: No Problem. ERB also has some shortcuts for this: You could also write: `'<%==j User.all.to_json %>'` instead. The extra equals sign is a shortcut for `raw` and the `j` is a shortcut for `escape_javascript`

Answer (score 0):

Generally whenever we convert a hash to json in ruby it tries to escape the quotes, there by producing parsing error. One way to fix this is printing the hash and on that calling the to_json method.

```
<%= (puts User.all).to_json %>
```

Click [here](http://www.rexfeng.com/blog/2012/12/convert-a-ruby-hash-into-valid-json/) to read more.